# Terminology: Multiply a matrix by a row vector vs column vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for terminology to distinguish between multiplying a row vector times a matrix $\left(\mathbf{b}^{T}A\right)$ vs multiplying a matrix times a column vector $\left(A\mathbf{b}\right)$. Here are a few starting points:

- matrix-vector multiplication vs vector-matrix multiplication reads a bit more like "matrix/vector multiplication" where order may not necessarily be implied
- left multiplication vs right multiplication? It's not clear if the vector or matrix is the "left" part
- pre-multiplication vs post-multiplication? It's not clear if the vector or matrix is the "pre" part. However, this terminology appears frequently in discussion of graphics libraries like OpenGL (inconsistently).

Comment: I admit I haven't seen terminology that is particularly consistent or widespread. Usually you say something like "multiply _by_ the matrix on the left" or on the right and so that indicates that you're looking at the position of the matrix relative to the vector.

Comment: If one says "multiply a vector by a matrix" in a math context, it typically means $Ab$; vectors are typically represented as columns, and when we represent a linear transformation by a matrix, it is usually with the convention $Ab$ in mind. There are a few situations where the row vector usage appears (notably, stationary distributions in Markov chains), where the use of row vectors is usually clarified in writing. In general, I don't think there is an established term to distinguish the two; the simplest and clearest thing to do is to explicitly write out what you mean: $Ab$ or $b^\top A$.